# XML sequence with JAX-WS

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, code-generation

Is there any way to make default WSDL being generated by JAX-WS (returned via `?wsdl`) to use XML `choice` instead of `any` and `sequence`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the XML schema in the `<types/>` part of the WSDL. The generation of this schema is not governed by JAX-WS, but by the JAXB specification. This is the specification for the data binding in JAX-WS.

But to actually answer your question: Yes, you can do that with an appropriate `@XMLElements` annotation in the class that represents your datatype. For example, take a web service interface like this:

```java
@WebService
public interface Chooser {

    String chooseOne(Choice myChoice);

}
```

Then the contents of your XSD depend on the structure of the `Choice` class. You can force the generation of a `choice` element through something like this:

```java
public class Choice {

    @XmlElements(value = { @XmlElement(type = First.class),
            @XmlElement(type = Second.class) })
    private Object myChoice;

}
```

Classes `First` and `Second` are possible elements in the choice. The schema generated from this code looks like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="choice">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="myChoice" type="tns:first"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="myChoice" type="tns:second"></xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This still wraps the `choice` in a `sequence`, but as there is only one element in the `sequence`, this doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution! To avoid parsing troubles (got ones at SoapUI), I put an unique `name` for each `element` of the `choice`. That was easy after undestanding the basic idea ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Using a unique `name` here makes sense, of course.